# how to uninstall an install4j windows collector in quiet mode?

Tags: install4j

I created a windows installer using install4j. /? does not show any option for quiet uninstallation. Tried "-u" and google but did not help. Does anybody know? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the argument `-q` to the uninstaller, it will be executed in unattended mode.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, I thought I need to use "msiexec.exe /x MyProductCode" like other msi installers. Seems install4j creates an uninstall.exe which can be run "uninstall.exe -q" to uninstall the product silently.